# Rewrite last part of file read

Tags: fwrite, fread, fseek

I see how to change the pointer in a file to read just part of the file (fseek).
Does setting the pointer for rewriting ('fwrite') part of the file work the same way?
After the 'fread' do I leave pointer alone or backup from current position to rewrite what I just read?
Note the idea is to exchange two blocks of the file for randomization.

Comment: Could you provide some feedback on my answer to your question or accept it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes `fwrite` works like `fread`. After `fread`, you need to `fseek` to the position to write to. Here's an example:

```php
// get temporary directory
$tmp_dir = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

// get temporary file name in temporary dir
$tmp_filename = tempnam($tmp_dir, '');

// open temp file for read and write
$handle = fopen($tmp_filename, 'r+');

$str = 'the quick brown fox jumps over   the lazy dog';

echo($str . PHP_EOL);

// write string to file
$result = fwrite($handle, $str);

$pos = strpos($str, 'jumps');

// seek to jumps position
$result = fseek($handle, $pos);

// change jumps for sneaks under
$str2 = 'sneaks under';

$result = fwrite($handle, $str2);

// get file size
$file_size = filesize($tmp_filename);

// seek to file start
$result = fseek($handle, 0);

// read from file
$result = fread($handle, $file_size);

echo($result);

// close file
fclose($handle);
```

```sh
$ php src/fwrite.php
the quick brown fox jumps over   the lazy dog
the quick brown fox sneaks under the lazy dog
```